# Java. Check time range. How?

Tags: java, date, time, date-range

For example, I have input parameter this format: "`04:00-06:00`" or "`23:00-24:00`". Type of parameter - `String`.

And in my method I must check, that time range in input parameter NOT before current time. How I can do it?

More details:

> input time range: "`12:00-15:00`"
>
> current time: `16:00`.

In this case, method must return `false`.

Another example:

> input time range: "`10:30-12:10`"
>
> current time: `09:51`.

method must return `true`.

Can you please give me some idea or algorithm?  How I can implement this method?

Comment: Should this be marked as homework?

Comment: No. This is not a homework. you're wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you should probably just learn to use [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

That said, since the times are all zero padded, you can just compare strings lexically.

```
public static boolean inRange(String time, String range) {
  return time.compareTo(range.substring(0, 5)) >= 0
      && time.compareTo(range.substring(6)) <= 0;
}
```

It's good practice to fail fast on malformed inputs.

```
private static final Pattern VALID_TIME = Pattern.compile("[012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]");
private static final Pattern VALID_RANGE = Pattern.compile("[012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]-[012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]");
```

and then put an assert at the top of `inRange`:

```
assert VALID_TIME.matcher(time).matches() : time
assert VALID_RANGE.matcher(range).matches() : range
```

EDIT:

If you really need to represent the current time as a `Date`, then you should compare it this way:

```
 public final class Range {
   /** Inclusive as minutes since midnight */
   public final int start, end;
   public Range(int start, int end) {
     assert end >= start;
   }

   /** @param time in minutes since midnight */
   public boolean contains(int time) {
     return start <= time && time <= end;
   }

   public static Range valueOf(String s) {
     assert VALID_RANGE.matcher(s).matches() : s;
     return new Range(minutesInDay(s.substring(0, 5)),
                      minutesInDay(s.substring(6));
   }

   private static int minutesInDay(String time) {
     return Integer.valueOf(time.substring(0, 2)) * 60
         + Integer.valueOf(time.substring(3));
   }
 }
```

Use `Range.valueOf` to convert from a `String`, convert your `Date` to a number of minutes since midnight in whatever timezone you like using whatever calendar implementation you like, and then use `Range.contains`.

Comment: current time it is Date but not String.

Comment: i agree with you. It is good solution... but I cant use any libraries. Only standart functionality and standart packages.

Comment: @user471011, Why on Earth can't you use libraries?  And what is "standard functionality?"  Does the `Range` class above not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date maxDate;
Date minDate;

//Parse range to two substrings
//parse two substrings to [HH, MM]
//for HH && MM parseInt()
//
minDate= new Date.SetHour(HH); minDate.SetMinute(MM);
//repeat for max date

if(currentDate.Before(maxDate) && currentDate.After(minDate))
{
return true;
}
else
return false;
```

Comment: setHours and setMinute are Deprecated methods.

Comment: My apologies I was reading old documentation use the equivalent methods in the Calendar class. e.g. maxDate = new Calendar(); maxDate.set(HOUR,HH); currentDate.after(maxDate);